# How to use webpack proxy devserver pathRewrite?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'm currently struggling with rewriting the proxy path to the api server. 
In my setup what I do is for api request, I delegate it to the proxy server and only for js/html/css `webpack-dev-server` is used.

Following is what I'm using:

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/',
    disableHostCheck: true,
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        pathRewrite: {'???' : ''} //Need to append http://localhost:3000/MySite1/api
  }
}
```

So, How do I append /MySite1 to api request before it proxies to the localhost:3000?

E.g. 
If the request is : 
http://localhost:8080/api, it should re write to http://localhost:3000/MySite1/api

Also, 
If the request is : 
http://localhost:8080, 
it should re write to http://localhost:3000/MySite1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try following:

```
devServer: {
inline: true,
port: 8080,
historyApiFallback: true,
publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/',
disableHostCheck: true,
proxy: {
     '/api': {
     target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      pathRewrite: function(path, req) {
       var replacedPath = path;
       if (path.indexOf("MySite1") === -1) {
         replacedPath = replacedPath.replace("/", "/MySite1/api/");
       }
       return replacedPath;
     },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Create proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000/MySite1/api",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

the ^/api part will be replaced with target

and then start the app with

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

Comment: I want to append `/MySite1` before /api not ignore

Comment: Sorry was still editing my file to match yours, that should work

Comment: No, what I meant is if the request is http://localhost:8080/api, it should re write it to http://localhost:3000/MySite1/api